# Microsoft Excel on Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel

Any ideas why F9 won't refresh this formula? If I click into the cell and hit my 'return' key then it will but is there any way to update the formula without clicking into the cell?

```
= "Record: "& (GetColorCount(R2:R6,$A$30)) & " - " & (5-(GetColorCount(R2:R6,$A$30)))
```

Thanks

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130686/how-do-i-recalculate-in-excel-for-mac

Comment: `GetColorCount` is that a UDF? As scripted it may not be volatile.